# what is VJSharp namespace?

Tags: .net

I want to run a program in .net 2008. It has an error: 
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VJSharp' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the [Visual J#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vjsharp/bb188594) language - it is probably not installed on your computer.

Download and install the [redistributable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vjsharp/bb188598) for your architecture and you should be OK.